# TableAdapter requires connection string?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, designer, strongly-typed-dataset

Is it just me or is it extremely short sighted that I can design a large type dataset and manipulate one in memory then save to some source (XML), yet when I want to design a query that taps into that dynamic dataset, the designer requires me to have a connection string to an existing database, *but that's entirely dynamic and no file even exists before the user creates one*.

The use case of the dataset is document-like, where the dataset is used to store information created by the user and saved to an XML file. Therefore I cannot possibly know where the connection is to.

Am I missing something here or do I really have to manually query the dataset because of this? I thought creating a query would just tap into the runtime dataset itself...

Comment: This was just a blip on the ADO team timeline, 10 years old already.  They moved on.  Like they did *many* times before.  No real substitute for actually learning the query syntax, the cake is a lie.

Comment: I do know SQL, I'm just sick of doing it in code, or looking through untyped `DataRows`. .NET 2.0 doesn't have `DataSetExtensions` so it looks like I have to do good ol' `foreach` loops on the typed data objects. I wish my company would upgrade the systems to .NET 3.5!

Comment: Sounds to me you should consider upgrading the company you work for.

Comment: Telstra? Yeah I think that'll happen in about one million years. We're still running Windows XP and only just updated to Service Pack 3. Large Corporation Syndrome!

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the [`TableAdapter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

`TableAdapter`s run SQL commands against *existing* databases to synchronize them with in-memory DataSets.

If you want to query an in-memory DataSet, you can use LINQ or DataViews.

Comment: What if I'm using .NET 2.0 and LINQBridge? I can't seem to query `TypedDataSet.TableName` for `TypedTableNameRow`.

Comment: Then you should be able to call `.Rows.Cast<RowType>()`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such method :(

Comment: Unless I'm missing a reference. .NET 2.0 + LINQBridge. `DataRowCollection.Cast<T>()` doesn't exist.

Comment: That should work; `DataRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable`.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/658fea84-21b9-43ec-9548-ffa893e6e250/

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;`?  What's the signature of `Enumerable.Cast<T>`?

Comment: I'm working with .NET 2.0. No LINQ, only LINQBridge which doesn't have DataSetExtensions.

Comment: I understand that.  Please answer my questions; this should work.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/658fea84-21b9-43ec-9548-ffa893e6e250/

Comment: What am I answering? There is no `DataRowCollection.Cast` method in .NET 2.0.

Comment: What's the signature of **Enumerable**.Cast<T>?

Comment: `DataRowCOllection` implements `IEnumerable` (non-generic), and `Cast<T>` should take an `IEnumerable`.  This should work.

Comment: I've said this before: *There is no Cast<T> method available, and there is no AsEnumerable()*. And I can't link to `System.Linq` because I'm not using .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Nick: Isn't LINQBridge in the namespace `System.Linq`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't include any DataSetExtensions.

Comment: @Nick: I know.  Howeber, it should have `Enumerable.Cast<T>`, and `DataRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using `DataTable.Select("expression")`.

As my `DataRows` are derived and I override `ToString()` I can do things like this.

```
var rows = dataSet.Staff.Select("TeamID = " + team.ID);
listBox.Items.AddRange(rows);

// Output
Smith, John
Goodall, Jane
```